# Flask is caching the returned response

Tags: python, flask

i have an app that return a json response (no HTML).
the problem is the response get cached like the following.

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response

# base api template
baseApi = {'status':None, 'message':None, 'data':{}}

@app.route('/getdata1')
def getData1():
  result = baseApi.copy()
  result['status'] = 'success'
  result['data'] = {'data1':'some data'}
  return make_response(jsonify(result), 200)


@app.route('/getdata2')
def getData2():
  result = baseApi.copy()
  result['status'] = 'success'
  result['data'] = {'data2':'some other data'}
  return make_response(jsonify(result), 200)
```

if i go to the link `/getdata1` then the rsponse will be as i expected

```
{
  "data": {
    "data1": "some data"
  },
  "message": null, 
  "status": "success"
}
```

but if after that i run the link  `/getdata2` i got the two results back

```
{
  "data": {
    "data1": "some data",
    "data2": "some other data"
  },
  "message": null, 
  "status": "success"
}
```

NOTE : the cache not happen in the browser , i have a mobile app , if i go to `/getdata1` in the mobile and then try `/getdata2` in the PC i got the same thing.
i tried this but it not seem to work !

```
@api.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public, max-age=0"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response
```

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you should try to use a deepcopy instead of shallow copy of your dictionnary.

the problem is not the cash but rather the dictionary has the same reference :
if we read about the definition of shallow copy

> A shallow copy creates a new object which stores the reference of the original elements.

To get a fully independent copy of an object you can use the copy.deepcopy() which is the case of this question.

Comment: A little explanation about what 'deepcopy' and 'shallow copy' are, and how they apply to this question would be helpful.